# Connecting Raspberry pi with iPhone / iPad application

Tags: python, ios, iphone

I'm working on home automation using raspberry pi and all i want to do controll my home electricity using mobile application, this is my project ,I'm new to networking i want to know what is the best way to communicate to my electric device using mobile , e.g I wrote a code for electronics in python and now i want to write a program in swift which will than can easily communicate with python and turn on and off the switches easily...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be the process which could take some efforts to do it.But i will guide you through some of the steps you can process.

1. You have to build a web server for communicating between raspberry pi and iPhone.Since you know python , Django or Flask would be the go to way.Create web server that communicates the relays which are connected with Raspberry-pi.I would share a [link](http://internetofthings-pune.blogspot.in/2013/10/home-automation-with-raspberrypi-python.html) that helped me to do so.
2. Now you want an iPhone app to do the control.If you have the knowledge of swift programming make APIs in Django or Flask web server and call it with your application.

This would be the common steps you need to do for controlling your lights via an iPhone App.